# Show vector layers through Leaflet.MagnifyingGlass on react-leaflet 4

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am implementing the '[Leaflet.MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.MagnifyingGlass)' on my typescript react-leaflet v4 project. I am able to show the magnifying glass on the tile layer however, I am not sure, how to implement it on the already overlaid vector layer.

```
function Lense (){
  const lenseLayer = useMap();
  const magnifiedTiles = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
   useEffect(() => {
    
    L.magnifyingGlass({
      layers: [magnifiedTiles]
        //layers: [PolylineDecorator]
    
    }).addTo(lenseLayer)

  }, [lenseLayer]);
  return <></>;
}


export default function App(): JSX.Element {
   <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{height: 'calc(100% - 30px)'}}>
   <TileLayer
 attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' />

{currentData?.movingActors.map(line =>(<PolylineDecorator key={line.id}
                polyline={positions} color={modeColor(line.mode)}/>))} 
<Lense />  
</MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

As one can see, that at the moment, magnifying glass only is laid to tile object. I need to lay it on top of the polylindedecorator object. The function is defined as

```
function PolylineDecorator({ polyline,color }) {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

  var x = L.polyline(polyline, {color}).arrowheads({ size: '5%' });
  x.addTo(map);
  }, [map]);
  
  return null;
}
```

Any suggestions, how can I achieve that.
PS I have already tried react-leaflet-magnifying-glass, but it is not compatible with the latest react-leaflet version.